# Snowflake dynamic SQL: quoting parameters

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Based on Snowflake docs:

> [Dynamically Creating a SQL Statement](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#label-example-of-dynamic-sql-in-stored-procedure)
>
> **As stated in SQL Injection (in this topic), be careful to guard against attacks when using dynamic SQL.**
>
> Create the stored procedure. This procedure allows you to pass the name of a table and get the number of rows in that table (equivalent to select count(*) from table_name):
>
> ```
> create or replace procedure get_row_count(table_name VARCHAR)
>     returns float 
>     not null
>     language javascript
>     as
>     $$
>     var row_count = 0;
>     // Dynamically compose the SQL statement to execute.
>     // Note that we uppercased the input parameter name.
>     var sql_command = "select count(*) from " + TABLE_NAME;
>     // Run the statement.
>     var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
>            {
>            sqlText: sql_command
>            }
>         );
>     var res = stmt.execute();
>     // Get back the row count. Specifically, ...
>     // ... first, get the first (and in this case only) row from the
>     //  result set ...
>     res.next();
>     // ... then extract the returned value (which in this case is the
>     // number of rows in the table).
>     row_count = res.getColumnValue(1);
>     return row_count;
>     $$
>     ;
> ```

The provided example does not look safe: `"select count(*) from " + TABLE_NAME;` - simple string concatenation

So it is possible to run code like:

```
CALL get_row_count('TAB');    -- intended use
CALL get_row_count('(SELECT * FROM TAB UNION ALL SELECT * FROM TAB) s'); -- subquery
```

---

First idea was to run code by using `TABLE/IDENTIFIER` function(in worksheet it would look like):

```
SET TABLE_NAME = 'TAB';  -- works
SET TABLE_NAME = '(SELECT * FROM TAB UNION SELECT * FROM TAB) s'; 
-- error: error line 1 at position 27 invalid identifier '$TABLE_NAME'
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE($TABLE_NAME);
```

And as part of procedure:

```
var sql_command = "SET TABLE_NAME = " + TABLE_NAME + "; SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE($TABLE_NAME);";
```

But it won't work since:

> *Execution error in stored procedure GET_ROW_COUNT: **Multiple SQL statements in a single API call are not supported; use one API call per statement instead**.*

---

Using `TABLE/IDENTIFIER` and binding variable:

```
create or replace procedure get_row_count(table_name VARCHAR)
returns float 
not null
language javascript
as
$$
var row_count = 0;
// Dynamically compose the SQL statement to execute.
// Note that we uppercased the input parameter name.
var sql_command = "select count(*) from TABLE(:1)";
// Run the statement.
var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
       {
       sqlText: sql_command,
       binds: [TABLE_NAME]
       }
    );
var res = stmt.execute();
res.next();
row_count = res.getColumnValue(1);
return row_count;
$$
;
```

Call:

```
CALL get_row_count('TAB'); --works
CALL get_row_count('(SELECT * FROM TAB UNION ALL SELECT * FROM TAB) s');
-- SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 0 unexpected '('.
```

Questions:

1. Is it possible to somehow run multiple statements as a single batch(`snowflake.createStatement`)?
2. Is there is an option to **safely quotename** within JS, sort of:

   `var sql_command = "select count(*) from " + FUNC(TABLE_NAME);`
3. Are there any potential flaws with `TABLE` and binding values approach?

Comment: Re: batch execution, you can roll your own of course: `this.executeMany = (s) =>  s.split(';').map(sqlText => snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText }).execute())`

Comment: @waldente Thank you, I will check this out. Will they be in the same context(i.e. if one of the statment is `SET var ...` will the next query be able to use it?

Comment: Yup.  For example, you can do: `executeMany ('set x=1; select $x')`.